# Ionic Application Development - White Screen of Death Issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-resource

I have just started learning Ionic and Angular.

After reading basic documentation related to Angular and Ionic, I was following the tutorial from this [site](http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/install-ionic.html) to develop the sample application myself.

I am able to load the application and see the data related to playlists, but after integrating 'Angular ngResource', to fetch the live data, related to sessions - by calling Rest API mentioned in the tutorial, I am not able to load the application in the browser (Blank white screen appears).

You can refer the application code with my changes here:

https://github.com/bhushanbaviskar/Angular-Ionic.git

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing at least inclusion of the ngResource and `starter.services` to your app in your app.js like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngResource'])
```

Then in your index.html you have a lot of typos, you should replace these parts with the code below:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- Angular ngReource-->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

There was ngResource `<script type="">` should be **src=""** and also the services.js had a typo `servcies.js` which should be **services.js**. Services.js also was declared as `type` and need to be changed to **src**.

Comment: After adding this dependency as well no change in the output.

Comment: I updated my answer. With this it should work. A lot of typos and things like that in your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.
I missed some of the dependencies and also the server URL was pointing to the wrong server. Now corrected everything and application is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, nice to hear that you got everything solved :) Glad I could help in some way at least.